# Buttons not getting replaced in CMFCToolbar at runtime

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I am using CMFCToolbar in a CMFCDesktopAlertDialog which is contained inside a CMFCDesktopAlertWnd. Initially I create the window and insert 3 buttons. Then on some action, I want to change those buttons to 2 or 3 different buttons. I tried using CMFCToolbar::RemoveAllButtons() & then InsertButton(). However, it did not work. When RemoveAllButtons() is called, all button get removed however new buttons are not inserted.

Comment: If your code doesn't show the desired behavior, it helps if you provide that code, ideally a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved after calling AdjustLayout after inserting the buttons.
The code is as below.

```
void MyClass::ReplaceButtons()
{
    m_m_myMFCToolbar.RemoveAllButtons();

    if(condition1)
    {
        m_myMFCToolbar.InsertButton( CMFCToolBarButton(ID_BUTTON1, 0, _T("MyText1"), FALSE, TRUE ) );
        m_myMFCToolbar.InsertButton( CMFCToolBarButton(ID_BUTTON2, 1, _T("MyText2"), FALSE, TRUE ) );
    }
    else
    {
        m_myMFCToolbar.InsertButton( CMFCToolBarButton(ID_BUTTON3, 2, _T("MyText3"), FALSE, TRUE ) );
        m_myMFCToolbar.InsertButton( CMFCToolBarButton(ID_BUTTON4, 3, _T("MyText4"), FALSE, TRUE) );
    }

    m_myMFCToolbar.AdjustLayout();  // This was added to resolve the issue

    CSize sizeToolBar = m_myMFCToolbar.CalcFixedLayout( FALSE, TRUE );
    m_myMFCToolbar.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, sizeToolBar.cx, sizeToolBar.cy, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER );
}
```